# Not able to plot graph correctly when a 'string' type is converted to 'int' in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

i am fetching some attribute values from xml , which are numeric in nature but coming as type 'string'

i am converting those **'strings'** type to **'int'** , and trying to plot a Bar graph in Bokeh.
The graph is not populating correctly (attached)[image: Bokeh Graph].  Any suggestion ?

Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
#String values fetched from xml
var='5'
var1='6'
#Converting string to int
var=int(var)
var1=int(var1)

#Creating a dataframe
d = {'col1': [var], 'col2': [var1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df

#Output
#   col1  col2
#0     0     4

#Displaying with Bokeh

p=Bar(df)
output_file("bar.html")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: `Bar` is part of the old, deprecated `bokeh.charts` API that has since been completely removed from core Bokeh. It is still available as the `bkcharts` package, but it is ***completely unmaintained and unsupported***. It should not be used for any new work at this point.

---

However, recent work greatly improved the support for bar and other categorical plots using the stable, supported `bokeh.plotting` API. There is [large new User's Guide Section](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) purely dedicated to explaining and demonstrating many kind of bar charts, both simple and sophisticated. Moreover, now that bar plots are easy to make using standard `bokeh.plotting` calls, the [general guidance and documentation for hover tools](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool) now applies as well.

It's not quite clear to me from your example code what you are trying to accomplish. Here is a very stripped down version of something that might be similar:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(x_range=['col1', 'col2'])
p.vbar(x=['col1', 'col2'], top=[5, 6], width=0.8)

output_file("bar.html")
show(p)
```

That code produces this output:

[image]

Here is a more complete example of a simple bar chart using pandas statistics (similar to what `Bar` would do) with hover tool using the "cars" sample data and the `bokeh.plotting` API:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

output_file("groupby.html")

df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
group = df.groupby('cyl')

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tools="")
p.vbar(x='cyl', top='mpg_mean', width=0.9, source=group)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Avg MPG", "@mpg_mean")]))

show(p)
```

Which produces the following result

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking far..Thanks bigreddot